# Creating a queue to handle jobs triggered by FileSystemWatcher

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, queue, filesystemwatcher

I have built a small tray app that will watch a folder and when a new file is added it runs a job. The job is to watch for video files and convert them to .mp4 using handBrakeCli. I have all this logic worked out. The problem I run into is that if there is more than one file I want it to queue the job til the prior one is complete. I am fairly new to c# and I am not sure of the best way to handle this.

one idea is to create a queue somehow, a file to store the commands in order maybe, then execute the next one after the process is complete. We are dealing with large movie files here so it can take a while. I am doing this on a quad core with 8gb of RAM and it seems to generally take about 30mins to complete a full length movie. I just dont know how to do this.

here is the code I have so far. there are some bits in here that are for future functionality so it refers to some classes that you wont see but it doesnt matter as they aren't used here. any suggestions are welcome.

```
    public void Watcher()
    {
        FileSystemWatcher watcher = new FileSystemWatcher();

        watcher.Path = textBox1.Text + "\\"; //path to watch
        watcher.Filter = strfilter; //what types to look for set to * and i will filter later as it cant accept an array
        watcher.NotifyFilter = NotifyFilters.FileName | NotifyFilters.DirectoryName; //properties to look at
        watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = true; //scan subdirs
        watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);

        //TODO: make this only run if the files are of a certain type
        watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = true; // start the watcher
    }

    static bool IsFileLocked(FileInfo file)
    {
        FileStream stream = null;

        try
        {
            stream = file.Open(FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None);
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
            //the file is unavailable because it is:
            //still being written to
            //or being processed by another thread
            //or does not exist (has already been processed)
            return true;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
                stream.Close();
        }

        //file is not locked
        return false;
    }

    // Define the event handlers. 
    private void OnChanged(object source, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    {
        string sFile = e.FullPath;
        //check that file is available
        FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(sFile);
        while (IsFileLocked(fileInfo))
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }

        if (System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("HandBrakeCLI").Length != 0)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(500);
        }
        else
        {
            //hbOptions hbCl = new hbOptions();
            //hbCli = hbCl.HbCliOptions();
            if (textBox3.Text != "")
            {
                hbCli = textBox3.Text.ToString();
            }
            else
            {
                hbCli = "-e x264 -q 20 -B 160";
            }
            string t = e.Name;
            string s = t.Substring(0, t.Length - 4); //TODO: fix this its not reliable
            file = e.FullPath;
            string opath = textBox1.Text.ToString();
            cmd = "-i \"" + file + "\" -o \"" + opath + "\\" + s + ".mp4\" " + hbCli;

            try
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < Ext.Count(); i++)
                {
                    if (e.Name.Contains(Ext[i]))
                    {
                        Process hb = new Process();
                        hb.StartInfo.FileName = "D:\\Apps\\Handbrake\\Install\\Handbrake\\HandBrakeCLI.exe";
                        hb.StartInfo.Arguments = cmd;

                        notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = "Now Converting";
                        notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = file;
                        notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(2000);

                        hb.Start();
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) //ok button
    {
        //add each array item to the list 
        for (int i = 0; i < filter.Count(); i++)
        {
            Ext.Add(filter[i]);
        }

        if (textBox1.Text != "" && textBox1.Text.Length > 2)
        {
            Watcher(); //call watcher to run
        }

        this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
    }
}
```

Comment: use a `Queue` and check it every time a job finishes?

Comment: Please remove code that isn't related to the question **directly**.

Comment: @abatishchev that wouldnt remove much. but i apologize for the length.

Comment: For example, you can replace some places with just methods' call having meaningful name. General flow is important but not concrete implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You way want to utilize WCF and MsmqQueueBinding:

- Service uses [NetMsmqBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.netmsmqbinding.aspx)
- Queue implemented for you using built-in into Windows queue called [MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx) (you can use MMC snap-it to control main, dead and poisoned letters queue. Both client and server Windows OS are bundled with it, turn it on in [Windows Features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa967729.aspx))
- Client puts process request into the queue and forgets about it
- Service receives it automatically and process
- Queue is durable, persisted and transactional (if you want)
- You can run a queue on the same machine or on another intranet server

See the follow wonderful tutorial:

- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 1)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx)
- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 2)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/13/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-2.aspx)
- [MSMQ, WCF and IIS: Getting them to play nice (Part 3)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/14/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-3.aspx)